# How to use plot3D::persp3D() to see plot in rgl device as with rgl::persp3d()?

Tags: r, rgl

I would like to plot my 3D function in a rgl device window using `plot3D` package. It allows me to rotate on x, y, z axis and scale. This is basic example with `rgl` package:

```
x <- seq(-10, 10, length = 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r })
z[is.na(z)] <- 1
rgl::persp3d(x, y, z)
```

Unfortunately this one is not open in rgl device:

```
plot3D::persp3D(x, y, z)
```

I am pretty sure that I have see it somewhere (maybe even in my experiments with that package). Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** maybe you were looking for the `plot3Drgl` package?

I don't think this is possible. `?plot3D::persp3D` says

> ‘persp3D’ is an extension to the **default persp plot**

(emphasis added). The "default `persp` plot" is built on the base R graphics, which uses a static "canvas-style" model - it cannot be dynamically rotated/zoomed.

Let's try looking for other packages with "3D" in their name ...

```
a1 <- available.packages()
grep("3D",rownames(a1),value=TRUE)
## [1] "arf3DS4"         "BaTFLED3D"       "DGVM3D"          "FPCA3D"         
## [5] "plot3D"          "plot3Drgl"       "VecStatGraphs3D"
```

We can try `plot3Drgl`, whose documentation (`?plot3Drgl`) says

> It will plot most (but not all) features from plots generated with
>        ‘plot3D’, except for the color keys and polygons.

On the other hand, it looks from experimentation as though it *does* handle color keys ...

```
plot3Drgl::persp3Drgl(x,y,z)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, Thank You! Nice that you put the way how you find it. :)